# Search Engine Friendly URL with .htaccess in xampp windows 10 on 64-bit

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo, xampp

I want to change my url to search engine friendly. i am using xampp 3.2.1 on windows 10 with 64-bit
My URLs are looking like this:

```
http://smc.edu.pk/app/site/?p=12&m=c&u=Swat_Medical_College-_The_Project_of_Swat_Medical_Complex
```

And I want to make it like this:

```
http://smc.edu.pk/app/site/12/c/Swat_Medical_College-_The_Project_of_Swat_Medical_Complex.html
```

i have tested with the following code with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/app/site/(\d+)/([a-z-]+)/(.+)\.html$ /?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3 [NC,L]
```

but it returns the following error when i am using the second url mentioned above:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

smc.edu.pk
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i have found the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /app/site/?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3 [NC,L]
```

I have change the RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /app/site/?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3 [NC,L]
```

And also put the RewriteBase /app/site/ on second line.
Now its working perfectly....

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this(not tested):

```
RewriteRule ^/app/site/(\d+)/([a-z-]+)/(.+)\.html$ /app/site/?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3 [NC,L]
```

Edit: It should be like this (tested and working):

```
RewriteRule ^app/site/(\d+)/([a-z-]+)/(.+)\.html$ /app/site/?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Dear @SomeHelpingDude, it is still showing the same error message.

Comment: Can you show us exact error you get? You can find it in apache logs

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2015:22:51:52 +0500] "GET /app/site/12/c/Swat_Medical_College-_The_Project_of_Swat_Medical_Complex HTTP/1.1" 404 1054 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"

Comment: yes, i have tried but still no luck, the same error

Comment: Please look at my completed .httaccess file code i am running now:

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/site/(\d+)/([a-z-]+)/(.+)\.html$ /app/site/?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3 [NC,L]

Comment: ok one thing i have not explained that is, i am using multiple virtual hosts on my xampp. Could it be the cause of this problem?

Comment: When you say "multiple virtual hosts", do you mean multiple folders?
If yes, change "/app/site/?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3" to "app/site/?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3" (notice removed slash).

Comment: Still not working... but when i change the last line to this: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?p=$1&m=$2&u=$3 [NC,L] it then change the url to: http://smc.edu.pk/app/site/12/c/app/site and with the same error message?